# Multiple SVG tags in an HTML document, IMG tag to reference to them - how?

Tags: html, image, svg

I want to have multiple SVG tags in an HTML file. I want them to be hidden until I reference to them with IMG tage. How can I do it?

```
<img src=??? width='100'height='100'>

<svg id='svg1' ...>
</svg>

<svg id='svg2' ...>
</svg>
```

Comment: you can't. img tags are for complete documents. Try researching the SVG <use> tag.

Comment: You will need to explain more. What exactly you intend to achieve. If what you need is hidden svg images (not img but svg) you can keep those shapes in a `<defs>` element till needed when you can `<use>` them.

Comment: @enxaneta, What I intend to achieve is to have one document that will be source for multiple images. In other words, avoid having separate document for each image. Apparently it's not possible, since img tags are for complete documents.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268215/how-to-reference-different-svgs-inside-the-same-svg-file-in-css-background/58275329#58275329

Comment: @enxaneta, I'll have to study the code...As far as I see it, there is CSS rule that is hiding all the images until they are invoked by the svg code...

Comment: @enxaneta, Unless I'm mistaken, it works with two SVGs in one document only if they differ in one SVG attribute.