# How to reference different SVGs inside the same SVG file in CSS background?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am creating a website and a very important requirement of this website is to have a minimal number of files. One place where I can reduce the number of files are the SVG files of the project. Currently this project is using 10+ SVG files and I hope to combine them all into one SVG sprite sheet. Since these SVG files were being used as background images in CSS:

```css
.class-name {
    background-image: url(/path/to/file.svg)
}
```

I now have an svg file, where each one of the previous SVG files is a symbol, so the svg file looks like this:

```xml
<svg>
    <symbol id="id1">....</svg>
    <symbol id="id2">....</svg>
    <symbol id="id3">....</svg>
...
</svg>
```

I wish to use these symbols in my CSS as follows:

```css
.class-name {
    background-image: url(/path/to/combined-file.svg#id1)
}
```

How can I use the SVG symbols in my background image.

I have already tried the following:

```css
.class-name {
    background-image: url(/path/to/combined-file.svg#id1)
}
```

and also

```css
.class-name {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,<svg><use xlink:href="path/to/combined-svg#id1/></svg>"");
}
```

I have also tried converting all the `<symbol>` tags to `<g>` tags but then all the images start to overlap each other and therefore it becomes pointless.

I am hoping for a solution where all my SVG are in one file and i can reference them individually in my CSS background image.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find this is possible.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example where I'm using svg sprites as background:

```css
div{width:300px;height:300px; border:1px solid;
background-image:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat);
  background-size:200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You can also use the #blackcat

The combined file looks like this:
(Please observe the `style` element where this rule `svg > svg:not(:target) {display: none;}` is hiding all the nested svg elements unless they are the target)

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100px" height="100px"  viewBox="0 0 225 225">

<style type="text/css">
 <![CDATA[  
    /* this is hiding all the nested svg elements unless they are the target*/
    svg > svg:not(:target) {
    display: none;
    }
     ]]> 
</style>
<desc>
<g id="cat">
<path id="body" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M121.506,108.953.....108.953z"/>
<path id="head" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M129.747,18.651......81.453z"/>
</g>
</desc>
<svg version="1.1" id="blackcat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 225 225">
<use xlink:href ="#cat" fill="black" />
</svg>
<svg version="1.1" id="redcat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 225 225">
<use xlink:href ="#cat" fill="red" />
</svg>

</svg>
```

I hope this is what you need.

You will find this explained in detail in this book: [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491921978)